# Android Material Design navigation drawer

Tags: navigation, drawer

I've used this code.
http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/
I want to change that.
I want to open a navigation drawer on the right.
in step 3.2 Adding Navigation Drawer
please help.
[Screenshot pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUDnl.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can start examining it: [Google Material Design](http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html)

In the meantime, I've never met such a sample.